# turn-on-rdebug-track-mode shows wrong line number in emacs

Tags: ruby, debugging, emacs, rdebug

I'm debugging a pretty large rails project and I've found the rdebug library for emacs to be a huge help. One annoyance, however, has been the pointer in the source showing the wrong line. In the example below, the code is executing line #277 (as shown in the left hand terminal) but the pointer in the code is on the next line (shown in the right hand terminal).

[image: rdebug track mode points to wrong line in source]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to track down this bug? I think this is in the ruby-debug-extras package but I haven't done any hacking on emacs so I don't even know the right mailing list to report this bug to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't claim to understand elisp or emacs functions particularly well, but I had the same problem (and some other issues too), and worked out a hack in [this commit](https://github.com/sebbacon/ruby-debug-extra/commit/42212bd665785814b6213838e07459c5f7807571) of my fork of ruby-debug-extra. The patch just adjusts the `lineno` variable by one:

```
--- a/emacs/rdebug-track.el
+++ b/emacs/rdebug-track.el
@@ -212,8 +212,8 @@ problem as best as we can determine."
       "line number cue not found"
     ;;else
     (let* ((filename (match-string rdebug-marker-regexp-file-group block-str))
-           (lineno (string-to-number
-           (match-string rdebug-marker-regexp-line-group block-str)))
+           (lineno (- (string-to-number
+                    (match-string rdebug-marker-regexp-line-group block-str)) 1))
```